# Raspberry Pi pico C/C++ SDK integration with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to get the Pico SDK working with VS-Code on Mac OSX.

As you can see in the screenshot below the include is not recognised.

I set the SDK path in `PICO_SDK_PATH` and stored this path as an environment variable.
Inside **VSCode** if I use the **CMake Tool extension** the build works correctly.

in the `c_cpp_properties.json` I explicitly included the SDK location

```json
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/Users/MY_USER/pico/pico-sdk/**"
            ],
```

[image: screenshoot]

Does anyone know how to remove this squiggly lines when including pico headers ?

Comment: In your test program must be a cmake file. Can you show this file?

Comment: You must include the library pico in your cmake file and recompile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `"/Users/MY_USER/pico/pico-sdk/**"`

This seems incorrect. Try this:

```json
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
    "~/pico/pico-sdk/**"
],
```

`~` points to the home directory. On Windows this is `C:\Users\USERNAME` and on Linux `/home/USERNAME`.

> Inside VSCode if I use the CMake Tool extension the build works correctly.

This is because the compiler does not use the settings from `c_cpp_properties.json`. Instead they are used for IntelliSense to work correctly, see [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/configure-intellisense-crosscompilation).